# How to calculate $\iint_D y\, dx\, dy$, $(D = \{(x, y) : x \le y \le 2x, 0 \le x \le 3\} )$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How to calculate $$\iint_D y\, dx\, dy,$$ where $$D = \{(x, y) \mid x \le y \le 2x, 0 \le x \le 3\} )?$$

This is the first time I have to solve such question, so I have definitely no idea how to do it.

If you can help me HOW to solve it, and not SOLVE IT for me,

I'll be very thankful.

What is the $D$ below the inner integral?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangular domain $D = \{(x, y) \mid x \le y \le 2x, 0 \le x \le 3\}$ is [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Normal_domains_on_R3) with respect to the $x$-axis, and $f(x,y)=y$ is a continuous function over $D$; then
$$\iint_D f(x,y)\, \operatorname{d}x \operatorname{d}y=\int_0^3\left(\int_x^{2x}y \operatorname{d}y\right)\operatorname{d}x$$

Check the solution here:

> $$\iint_D f(x,y)\, \operatorname{d}x \operatorname{d}y=\int_0^3\underbrace{\left(\int_x^{2x}y \operatorname{d}y\right)}_{\left.\frac{y^2}{2}\right|_x^{2x}=\frac{4x^2-x^2}{2}}\operatorname{d}x=\frac{3}{2}\int_0^3x^2\operatorname{d}x=\frac{3}{2}\left.\frac{x^3}{3}\right|_0^{3}=\frac{27}{2}.$$

Comment: So it's simply a Calculus1 integral..?

Comment: it reduces to the evaluation of simple integrals before with respect to $y$ and then $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you can apply Fubini's theorem, and integrate first with respect to $y$.

Comment: In my opinion, this is an answer to the request "If you can help me HOW to solve it, and not SOLVE IT for me". I did NOT solve it completely, but I explained HOW to solve it. I think one should carefully read the question before the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The D is the region on the xy plane on which you integrate.

$\int\limits_0^{3}\int\limits_x^{2x} y    \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x $

first integrate $\int_x^{2x} ydy$ as if it were a single integral and as if the x is a constant. let's call whatever you get (result) .  Then do the second integral with (result) inside $\int_0^3 (result) dx$

Answer (score -1):

$$\int \int_D ydxdy $$
= $$\int_0^3 \int_x^2xydxdy$$

= $$\int_0^3(x\int_x^2ydy)dx$$

= $$\int_0^3\frac{4x-x^3}{2}dx$$

Now you can do it

Comment: Can you please explain every step?